# Feeding a reactive variable in an R markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

I have designed an R markdown doc that has combination of r code chunks, inline r, and various render functions.

I've put a couple of Shiny inputs in the doc, and I want to feed those inputs into two variables early in the r code, and then the various code segments later in the doc can depend on those variables.  Some examples of the code are below.

I am having problems getting this doc to work.  ("Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)")

Would be great if I could get some advice on how to edit the code to work.

````
# set up shiny input


``` {r echo = FALSE}
inputPanel(
textInput("fmno","Enter code", placeholder = "Code"),
selectInput("comparator", "Choose your comparator", choices = c("OP", "GE"),        selected = "GE")
)
```

# feed inputs into variables in r code for use later in doc

```{r} 
fmno <- reactive({get(input$fmno)})
comparator <- reactive({get(input$comparator)})
person_table <- person_table[person_table$fmno == fmno, ]
op_table <- op_table[op_table$op == op, ]
ge_table <- ge_table[ge_table$ge == ge, ]
if (comparator == "OP") {
  comp_table <- op_table
  comp <- op
  } else {
  comp_table <- ge_table
  comp <- ge
  }
```
````

Comment: I'm more used to `shiny` on it's own (not in `.Rmd`), but are you sure you need those `get()` functions? Maybe start simple like in your second chunk do `fmno_val <- input$fmno; person_table <- person_table[person_table$fmno == fmno_val, ]; return(person_table)`. Then after that chunk create a new one where you do `test <- fmno(); print(test)`.